# How to deal with background geofencing in 2022?

Tags: java, android, geofencing, android-geofence

### Here is the situation:

When a user creates a Geofence, I save it to backend and I register a Geofence with the OS. But whenever my app restarts I fetch geofences from my backend and reregister them with the OS again, since they keep disappearing.

I have two classes `MainActivity` and `FormActivity`. Both of these activities register Geofences, so I have extracted the actual registration to an ordinary POJO `Geofences.java`

### **Here is the problem:**

**Now the strange thing is, triggers are only received when a map activity is on the screen. I do have a map activity in my app, but it doesn't even have to be my map-activity, even if I launch google maps geofence triggers start firing.**

What am I doing wrong?

### Geofences.java:

```
public class Geofences {

    private final String TAG = Geofences.class.getSimpleName();
    private final float RADIUS = 150.0F; //meter
    private boolean success = false;

    private final int LOITERING_IN_MILLISECONDS = 30000;// 30 seconds

    public boolean doGeofenceStuff(GeoTemp newTemp, String geofenceId, PendingIntent pendingIntent, GeofencingClient geofencingClient) {

        Geofence geofence = createGeofence(newTemp, geofenceId);
        GeofencingRequest geofencingRequest = createGeofenceRequest(geofence);
        geofencingClient.addGeofences(geofencingRequest, pendingIntent)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            success = true;
                            Log.i(TAG, "onComplete: DEBUG-Message: Geofence has been added.");

                        } else {
                            success = false;
                            Log.i(TAG, "onComplete: Geofence could not be added");
                        }
                    }
                }); // handle error here
        return success;
    }

    // Create a Geofence
    private Geofence createGeofence(GeoTemp geoTemp, String geofenceId) {


        long expiration = getExpirationForCurrentGeofence();
        if (expiration < 1) {
            Log.e(TAG, "createGeofence: Can't create Geofence, since expiration is less than zero");
            return null;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "createGeofence");
        return new Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId(geofenceId)
                .setCircularRegion(getLat(), getLong(), RADIUS)
                .setExpirationDuration(expiration)
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                .setLoiteringDelay(LOITERING_IN_MILLISECONDS)
                .build();
    }

    // Create a Geofence Request
    private GeofencingRequest createGeofenceRequest(Geofence geofence) {
        Log.d(TAG, "createGeofenceRequest");
        return new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
                .setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_DWELL)
                .addGeofence(geofence)
                .build();
    }

}
```

This POJO `Geofences.java` is then used by two of my activities:

### MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private final int GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE = 0;
    private GeofencingClient geofencingClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        geofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(this);
        getCurrentTemps();
    }

    private void refreshGeofence(GeoTemp temp, String id) {
        new Geofences().doGeofenceStuff(temp, id, createGeofencePendingIntent(), geofencingClient);
    }
    private void getCurrentTemps() {
        List<GeoTemp> currentGeofences = getUpdatedList();
        currentGeofences.forEach(geoTemp -> {
            refreshGeofence( geoTemp, id);
        });
    }
    private PendingIntent createGeofencePendingIntent() {
        Log.d(TAG, "createGeofencePendingIntent");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationAlertIntentService.class);
        return PendingIntent.getService(
                this, GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
}
```

There is one more activity which uses Geofences.java to register geofences with the operating system.

### Update:

I have found out that, if any other app (including mine) requests for location lock, geofence triggers fire. I need them to fire in the background.

Comment: I am wondering if you got a solution, I am struggling with the same issue.

Comment: nope, could never find true solution :D

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue when working with geofencing in android.

This happens due to [background restrictions](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) added in Android Oreo and later.

OS does not allow your app to start service when it is in background so you won't receive geofence trigger.

To handle this:

- Add broadcast receiver to receive intent. (This receiver will get
  geofence alert even when app is in background)
- Replace service with JobIntentService. (This will use OS JobSchedular
  and run even with background restrictions)
- Get broadcast from pending intent instead of service.

Checkout this [sample project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/Geofencing) for further clarifications.

Comment: but I do get the triggers, only if ANY app requests geo fix.

Comment: @Marci-man Did you find a solution? Even if your app is killed (Activity swiped away)?

Comment: Whenever location is fetched by OS (requested by your or any other app), geofence is triggered if its requirements are met i.e. user moved inside or out of geofence.

Comment: One solution is to get location fix after some fixed interval like 5 or 10 minutes. This way geofences are triggered as location is fetched and compared by OS against registered geofences.