# The Geofence entry and exit are being captured late in the some mobiles

Tags: location, maps, background-service, geofencing

we have developed geofencing for capturing entry and exit times at specific locations in background. In some mobile phones, entry and exit are captured with a delay of 2-4 minutes.
We would appreciate your help in fixing this

I have used Broadcast Receiver to receive the Geofence alerts, I register the receiver in android manifest file. But in android document it said that alerts will be late from android O and above if  Background Location Limits exists.
Question :

1. If I register the receiver dynamically using mContext.reigsterReceiver() programatically. The delay in receiving geo fence alert will not be their ?
2. If we register the receiver in Android Manifest or via programtically (mContext.registerReceiver()). Their will be delay in receiving geo fence alerts ?
3. My application need Geo fence alerts immediately with out any delay in both the cases Either Application in Foreground or Background, What should I do for that?

Mainly samsung and moto mobiles it is not working.

Comment: you might be interested in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56017183/1545993